# Flask - Unit Test with testing app context

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking

I have the following module live under db.db.Db, and it's inside a Flask application. It use the app.config variable to connect to a database, How do I overwrite these setting when I writing unit test cases? How do I have a different app context with dummy config variable from Flask?

```
import psycopg2


class Db(object):
    def __init__(self):
        import app
        conn_string = "host='{}' port='{}' dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format(app.app.config['DB_HOST'], \
                      app.app.config['DB_PORT'], app.app.config['DB_NAME'], app.app.config['DB_USER'], \
                      app.app.config['DB_PASSWORD'])
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to [create your app with a function](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/20/), instead of having a single app instance created at import time.

If you're only ever hitting the database in a request context, then you can use [`flask.current_app`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.current_app) to access the current app context.

For example:

```
from flask import current_app
import psycopg2


class Db(object):
    def __init__(self):
        conn_string = "host='{}' port='{}' dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}'".format(current_app.config['DB_HOST'], \
                      current_app.config['DB_PORT'], current_app.config['DB_NAME'], current_app.config['DB_USER'], \
                      current_app.config['DB_PASSWORD'])
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

Then your tests can each create their own app, and change the config values to whatever they like.